# a simple one -- JPA @OneToMany is generating SQL for table that does not exist

Tags: sql, jpa, one-to-many

I have a simple JPA project running (with IBM RAD 7.5 on WebSphere 7).

I have a Customer that has many Orders.  Looks like this ...

```
@Entity
public class Customer /* in table CC_CUSTOMER */
  @Id
  BigDecimal customerId;
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Order> orderList;
```

...

```
@Entity
public class Order /* in table CC_ORDER */
  @Id
  BigDecimal orderId;
  Customer customer;
```

The problem I have is when I try to retrieve a Customer, I get an error because the SQL that's being generated by JPA contains a select for a non-existant table called: CC_CUSTOMER_CC_ORDER

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing @ManyToOne annotation at Customer customer; and mappedBy="customer" at @OneToMany annotation

Customer entity

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="customer")
private List<Order> orderList;
```

Order entity

```
@ManyToOne
Customer customer;
```

Because of that JPA thinks that your relationship is unidirectional and this is solved by join table named CC_CUSTOMER_CC_ORDER. If you let your provider generate the schema the table should be generated.

Comment: Thanks -- a new problem, now the generate query is looking for a field in the ORDER table called ORDER.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMERID which doesn't exist -- any ideas?  (ORDER.CUSTOMERID does exist.)

Comment: FYI, I added a @JoinColumn(name="customerid") after the @ManyToOne and that new error when away.  However, my test is not loading in the Orders when I retrieve a customer.  (The fetch type is eager on the Customer.)  Any ideas?  (Or should I put in a new question?)

Comment: How do you insert the data into DB? Can you check that the tables contain correct values (especially if the customerid column in order table is filled)? If you insert using JPA dont forget to add order into the order list as well as to set the customer property in Order entity.